# npx dwio getting 405 Method Not Allowed - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/dwio/dwio

Tags: javascript, appium, appium-android

I am running this on terminal

> npx dwio

and getting error

```
npm ERR! code E405
npm ERR! 405 Method Not Allowed - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/dwio/dwio

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-20T13_41_02_619Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo, I suppose you meant `npx wdio` instead of `npx dwio`.